# Ansible: to how make Paramiko use ~/.ssh/config?

Tags: ssh, ansible, paramiko

Ideally, of course, I'd like Ansible to completely take care of this.

If this is not possible (why?!), then, at least, I want to be able to extract ~/.ssh/config contents into some other format and then make Ansible feed this to Paramiko. I am sure I'm not the first one faced with this task, so what's the accepted way of doing this?

I need this in order to use authorized_keys module to turn on passwordless authentication.

Btw, I wish Ansible emitted some warning when falling back to non-default backend (like Paramiko). I lost a couple of hours yesterday and actually had to download Ansible sources to figure out why perfectly running Ansible command suddenly stopped running when adding -k / --ask-pass option (yes, I am completely new to Ansible).

Comment: I have the same question and I can't believe this has not been answered in over an year

Answer (score 1):

You can define this configuration in the [Ansible configuration](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file) ini file or environment variables -- specifically the section for [`ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-ssh-args).